# Styling single row from HTML table

Tags: html, css

I am working on a asp.net mvc 3 application. I'm showing data from a database using table. basically the table has 4 columns but in certain cases there could be 2 or even 1 single column for the entire row. By using `if` statements I can catch those cases and manage them properly (using colspan to be more specific) and thus I can keep the structure of my table clean. However there is a default  behaviour  which I would really like to change (if possible) with some CSS.

When I have two columns on a row I would like each column to take exactly 50% from the whole width of the row. To make myself more clear, here is what I see now :

[image: Table]

At the very bottom, actually this is also the end of the table but still a row from the same table the two strings `Sign in here`. As you can see the left one is taking a lot less space than the right one. At the begining I was using different tables to manage this kind of stuff but I would really want to keep everything in one table and just adjust the width of the cells on current row where necessary. I can determine this row, I can attach some class to it, I just don't know what CSS to use to make each cell occupy the same space (And of course is it possible to do this at all)

P.S

Sorry, this is the code (Razor) that I use in my view to render this row :

```
<tr>          
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model[0][0].FieldValue))
        { 
            <td colspan="2">
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[0][0].FieldValue)
            </td>
        }
        else
        { 
            <td colspan="2">
            Sign in here
            </td>
        }         

        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model[1][0].FieldValue))
        { 
            <td colspan="2">
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[1][0].FieldValue)
            </td>
        }
        else
        { 
            <td colspan="2">
            Sign in here
            </td>
        }        

</tr>
```

Comment: Make the last tr > td with `colspan="4"` then create a table inside with two td`s, each `width:50%`, this way they will not be influenced by the other rows/columns

Comment: Well, what is the big difference between this and what I wrote was doing before (creating new table to handle this case?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any additional styles, a HTML table will structure it's cell widths as far as is possible to accommodate the data in the entire column.  There isn't any way of styling the width of cells specifically from one row to the next.

So, if you want to get two cells to fall exactly 50% each (whereas the cells for the other rows - where these cells are used - aren't equal-width), your best bet would be to inject an additional table (within the whatever the parent colspan is) with one row, two columns, each set to 50% width.

I'm sure you can extract this would into your current logic (and an external CSS file) but the resultant markup would look something like:

```
<td colspan="x">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:50%">cell content here</td>
            <td style="width:50%">cell content here</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Comment: If you going to get my comment and post as an answer, at least copy right it: It's colspan 4, not 2 because his table has 4 columns.